# JavaScript Tabs go up

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
      tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
      tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```html
<li><a href="#" class="tablinks active" onclick="openCity(event, 'general')">GENERAL</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'modes1')">MODES 1</a></li>
```

I have tabs in 
 to switch tabs.

When I click on tabs to switch, it works! But it scrolls up to the top of the page then switch. How to fix that scroll up?

Comment: Combine the snippets, as it would help others help you.

Comment: Remove `href="#"` from links, replace it with spans/divs.

Comment: In your `onclick` try to change everything to: `openCity( .... ); return false;`

Comment: Add `event.preventDefault()` in `openCity()`

Comment: for better practice use with [`classList`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwji-bDP2dvVAhUGKo8KHSCPD7YQFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FAPI%2FElement%2FclassList&usg=AFQjCNHl5HGg38jFQ1TEZv6ZBdarl_G85w) property instead of `classname`